# PHP createimagefromjpeg() How to include all image types

Tags: php, image, png, jpeg, imagecreatefrompng

is there a way that i can use createimagefromjpeg() to save an image from a url but allow all image file types?

It seems obvious that createimagefromjpeg only allows jpeg / jpg.

Here is my current process:

```
    // create the image and save it
    $imagefile = iageURL;
    $resource = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagefile);
    // X amount of quality is the last number
    imagejpeg($resource, "images/covers/imagename.jpeg", 50);
    imagedestroy($resource);
```

This works great because it allows me to reduce the image quality. But i get an error when trying to use anything other than a jpeg / jpg.

Is there a way around this? Or perhaps a better method of saving images (at a reduced quality) from a url.

Craig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the file type - the best way is to check the mime type if you can, then you can do a switch and utilize the other image creation functions in GD lib such as [imagecreatefromgif()](http://php.net/imagecreatefromgif) and [imagecreatefrompng()](http://php.net/imagecreatefrompng) etc:

```
switch($mime_type) {
    case 'image/jpeg':
    case 'image/jpg':
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
        break;
    case 'image/png':
        $img = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
        break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $img = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
        break;
}
```

Another option is for you to grab the image's data into a string and use [imagecreatefromstring()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) to create an image handle from raw data:

```
$filename = 'http://yoursite.com/yourlogo.jpg';
$img = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filename));
```

[From the manual:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) `These types will be automatically detected if your build of PHP supports them: JPEG, PNG, GIF, WBMP, and GD2.`

Comment: Perfect, simply changing the function to imagecreatefromtstring() worked. Thanks!